# PYTHON programming: Search and Replace text in a file

Tags: python

I am new to PYTHON and trying to write script which replaces text in a text file. This is what I have come up with using Python 3.1. But I am having some errors. Would somebody help me, please?

```
#****************************************************************
# a Python code to find and replace text in a file.
# search_replace.py : the  python script
#****************************************************************

import os
import sys
import fileinput

print ("Text to search for:")
textToSearch = input( "> " ) 

print ("Text to replace it with:")
textToReplace = input( "> " )

print ("File to perform Search-Replace on:")
fileToSearch  = input( "> " )   # "rstest.txt"
#fileToSearch=open('E:\\search_replace\\srtest.txt','r')

oldFileName  = 'old-' + fileToSearch
tempFileName = 'temp-' + fileToSearch

tempFile = open( tempFileName, 'w' )

for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
    tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, textToReplace ) )
tempFile.close()


# Rename the original file by prefixing it with 'old-'
os.rename( fileToSearch, oldFileName )

# Rename the temporary file to what the original was named...
os.rename( tempFileName, fileToSearch )

input( '\n\n Press Enter to exit...' )
```

---

Regards

Comment: It would be polite if you were more specific about the errors you are encountering, rather than making people read all your code and run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter a file path such as `"E:\\search_replace\\srtest.txt"`, oldFileName will be `"old-E:\\search_replace\\srtest.txt"` and tempFileName will be `"temp-E:\\search_replace\\srtest.txt"`, neither of which are valid.

Try doing something like this instead:

```
oldFileName  = "{}\\old-{}".format(*os.path.split(fileToSearch))
tempFileName = "{}\\temp-{}".format(*os.path.split(fileToSearch))
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I am not sure if this is an error in your putting your code online, but the body of your for loop is not indented.

```
for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, textToReplace ) )
tempFile.close()
```

Should be

```
for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
  tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, textToReplace ) )
tempFile.close()
```

Second, you are using the input() method where you most likely want raw_input(), which accepts string input such as characters to search. input() takes any python statement, including a string such as 'a string'

Comment: Hey thanks for a quick response!   Well Indentation is just  an issue of  putting my code  here:).  and  raw_input() ??  i read  on internet that  Python no longer supports  this command. that is why i  am not using it :(

Comment: I have successfully run your script with the indentation fixed and by replacing input() with raw_input(). Please read the difference I have described, and if it works for you, accept the answer.

Comment: i get the following error using raw_input()
>>  textToSearch = raw_input( "> ")
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: Hey sorry, forgot you were using Python 3.1, for which raw_input() was turned into input(). What sort of errors are you having? Please edit your question to include them. I'm running your script without errors using input() in Python 3.1

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your guidance and sorry  if my method of asking was a bit  unclear! 

I  just Installed 2.6 also and  used raw_input(). it worked fine:)  and  I used 3.1 again to  execute it after  moving the  target file  into root of drive and  its working fine! 

 but when i  try to use  a path like E:\\PYcodes\\search_replace\\srtest.txt 
using fileToSearch=open()   , i get a message "no such file or directory"